# Super with method parameters

Tags: java, stack

I came across this code and am trying to understand what super is doing here:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackWithMax extends Stack<Integer> {

Stack<Integer> s2;

public StackWithMax() {
    s2 = new Stack<Integer>();      
}

public void push(int value){
    if (value >= max()) {
        s2.push(value);
    }
    super.push(value);
}

public Integer pop() {
    int value = super.pop();
    if (value == max()) {
        s2.pop();           
    }
    return value;
}

public int max() {
    if (s2.isEmpty()) {
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    } else {
        return s2.peek();
    }
  }
}
```

When super.push(value) is called, what object is being modified?

What is the difference here between calling s2.push(value) and super.push(value), since super refers to a `Stack<Integer>` and s2 is a `Stack<Integer>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s2` is a member of `StackWithMax`, but `StackWithMax` also inherits from `Stack<Integer>`.
When you want to push into s2, you write `s2.push()`, but when you want to push into 'yourself', you call the push method you inherited. `super` keyword is used because you have also overridden the push method.

Answer (score 1):

There are **two** stacks here. StackWithMax is itself a stack. And it contains a second stack!

The calls to super methods address that first stack. So the difference is that there are actually two different data structures that get accessed here.

It is like a truck that has a car sitting on it. Both are vehicles and so you could start two engines. This code has two stacks at hand that can be manipulated.

In this special case it is required to use super like this - if that push method would just call push() - not super.push() - you would end up in an endless recursion and a stackoverflow exception.

Comment: an easy way to see this is to print out the stack of .this (StackWithMax) and the member stack (s2). you will see that they are different depending on the ints provided.